# Integration of our own customised CRM chat system into our website

Tags: web, software-design

I am interning at a company and I am stuck in one problem if anyone can help.

QUESTION: Our company has there own CRM software and I am working on website designing. I have a task to put there chat system which is in there CRM in the website using javascript, ajax, json or php either. Does anyone have any idea how I can tackle with this.